# Visual Basic MySQL cannot open database requested by login

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I decided to ask this question because I can't find the solution anywhere. My knowledge with visual basic and mysql is also very limited,just the basics.

I followed a video I saw on youtube on updating a mysql table connected to a visual basic project. Im connecting to a localhost using xampp.

when I did not include integrated security=true in the connections string it fails to login user root; when I included it that's when it says cannot open database requested by login

Here's the code I patterned from what I saw on youtube

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=testdb;integrated security=true;")

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE testtb SET Items = @test where id=1", connection)

        command.Parameters.Add("@test", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @PaulT. Hi, I named the table testtb.

Comment: If you want to connect to MySQL Database, check [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/115753-use-vbnet-to-connect-to-mysql/) article. I think that the way you try to connect is not for MySQL.

Comment: Hi @David- It seems that the way I was trying to connect is not for MySQL, the article you linked would probably solve my problem. Thank you !